# How to prevent CC-Cleaner to delete DevDocs.io cached data

Tags: google-chrome, cache, cookies

I am using DevDocs.io quite often when developing. It's quite handy when working offline fe. on the train or places where there is no immediate internet connection.

I'm also using CC-Cleaner on a sceduled timeframe to keep my laptop working optimally. However when it's cleaning the Chrome cache it keeps on deleting the DevDocs.io cached data, causing me not to be able to access the libraries necessary.

I have tried to exclude all DevDocs cookies and cached data, but I must be overlooking something since it is still deleting the libraries.

Therefore I wondered if someone had the same issues in the past or knows exactly which files to exclude so that CC-Cleaner can do its job without removing the data necessary to work offline.

It's imperative that the cookies and cached data are still being deleted, so unchecking those boxes is not an option (excluding the files is, if only I knew which ones).